# Can you rescale a PhotoImage in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I have two buttons. `button1` calls a function (`bt1`) which displays an image in the window and then deletes both buttons. `button2` calls a function(`bt2`) I would like this button to display the same image as button1 but by half the scale factor. I am thinking something like this:

```
scale_half_img = PhotoImage(file = 'Image.png', scale = 0.5)
```

Of course, this doesn't work but this is the sort of thing I am looking for.

Full code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()

def bt1():
    img = PhotoImage(file = 'Image.png')
    imglbl = Label(window, image = img, anchor = 'nw')
    imglbl.place(x = 0, y = 0, width = 865, height = 800)

    button1.destroy()
    button2.destroy()

def bt2():
    # display scaled down image

    button1.destroy()
    button2.destroy()




button1 = Button(window, text = 'Display Image', command = bt1)
button1.place(x = 10, y = 10, width = 200, height = 30)

button2 = Button (window, text = 'Display Rescaled Image', command = bt2)
button2.place(x = 10, y = 50, width = 200, height = 30)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: You can't do it with tkinter alone and will need to also use the PIL module.

Comment: @martineau: That's not entirely true. The Tkinter PhotoImage has the ability to scale up and down by removing or duplicating pixels via the `copy` method with the `subsample` and `zoom` options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `PIL.Image` to resize an image in tkinter. You can do it as follows:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
img = Image.open('<Path to Image>')
img = img.resize((img.size[0]/2, img.size[1]/2), Image.ANTIALIAS)
resized_image = ImageTk.Photoimage(img) # use this
```